# Selecting multiple sheets in VB

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I want to select multiple sheets for printing all sheets in a book apart from one, so far my code looks like this, recorded through a macro:

```
Sub Print_All()
  '
  ' Print_All Macro

    Sheets(Array("Class List", "Blank1", "Blank2", "Blank3", "Blank4", "Blank5", "Blank6" _
        , "Blank7", "Blank8", "Blank9", "Blank10", "Blank11", "Blank12", "Blank13", "Blank14", _
        "Blank15", "Blank16", "Blank17", "Blank18", "Blank19", "Blank20", "Blank21", "Blank22" _
        , "Blank23", "Blank24")).Select
    Sheets("Blank2").Activate
    Sheets(Array("Blank25", "Blank26", "Blank27", "Blank28", "Blank29", "Blank30")). _
        Select Replace:=False
    Sheets(Array("Blank1", "Blank2", "Blank3", "Blank4", "Blank5", "Blank6", "Blank7", _
        "Blank8", "Blank9", "Blank10", "Blank11", "Blank12", "Blank13", "Blank14", "Blank15", _
        "Blank16", "Blank17", "Blank18", "Blank19", "Blank20", "Blank21", "Blank22", "Blank23" _
        , "Blank24", "Blank25")).Select
    Sheets("Blank2").Activate
    Sheets(Array("Blank26", "Blank27", "Blank28", "Blank29", "Blank30")).Select _
        Replace:=False
    Range("F5:N10").Select
    Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
End Sub
```

it works fine but the problems occur if I ever want to change the name of a sheet. It returns an error as it is looking for the blanks. 
Is there a way to select the sheets without naming them in the code?

Comment: you want to select all sheets in your workbook except one , what is this sheet name (that you don't want to print) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can always refer to sheets not by names, but rather by their indeces, e.g. Sheet1 in a newly created workbook has index 1, Sheet2 - index 2 and so on.

Syntaxis as following: `yourWorkbook.Sheets(index as integer)`

So for example:

```
dim wbk as Workbook
set wbk = ActiveWorkbook

dim i as integer
wbk.Sheets(i).Select
```

EDIT:
Oh, please mind that sheets sometimes are deleted or moved within a workbook or outside of it. That given sheets' indeces do not necessarily correlate with their order within your workbook. To check indeces of sheets that you need you can either try and fail or use the loop as following

```
dim n as integer
for n = 1 to wbk.Sheets.count
    debug.print "index " & i, wbk.Sheets(i).name
next n
```

Comment: Oh, please mind that sheets sometimes are deleted or moved within a workbook or outside of it. That given sheets' indeces do not necessarily correlate with their order within your workbook. To check indeces of sheets that you need you can either try and fail or use the loop as following

Comment: `dim n as integer